# how to disable keyboard events for a cross domain iframe

Tags: iframe, keyboard-events

I have an iframe with its contents being an external one.

I need to restrict the keyboard access for this iframe, so that the user doesn't navigate using tab key. Is this possible ?

I tried the following which doesn't help

```
 <iframe  tabindex="-1" id='iframect'></iframe>
```

also used jquery keydown, not working either

```
$("#iframect").on('keydown',function(e)
    {             
            e.preventDefault();
    });
```